# How to understand $Y^{acc}\subseteq cl(Y)$?

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I need some help in understanding the last part of the proof shown in the image. The part I dont understand is why we have $cl(Y)^{acc}\subseteq cl(Y)$. Can it be that we are already using the property we need to prove?

Any comments on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an arbitrary topological space $(X, \mathscr{T})$. For any subset $M \subseteq X$ I will write $\dot{M}$ for the *derivative* of $M$ (i.e. the subset of all accumulation points of $M$).

By definition we have the following descriptions of *accumulation* points respectively *adherent* points:

$$\begin{align*}
x \in \dot{M} &\Leftrightarrow x \in X \wedge (\forall V)\left(V \in \mathscr{V}_{\mathscr{T}}(x) \Rightarrow V \cap M \setminus \{x\} \neq \varnothing\right)\\
x \in \overline{M} &\Leftrightarrow x \in X \wedge (\forall V)\left(V \in \mathscr{V}_{\mathscr{T}}(x) \Rightarrow V \cap M \neq \varnothing\right).
\end{align*}$$

It is obvious that if $x \in X$ is such that any neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ (with respect to the topology $\mathscr{T}$) intersects the set-theoretical difference $M \setminus \{x\}$, it will furthermore intersect $M$ itself, since $V \cap M \setminus \{x\} \subseteq V \cap M$. In other words, if $x$ is an accumulation point of $M$ it will automatically be adherent to $M$.

In contracted form this means that $\dot{M} \subseteq \overline{M}$ and since evidently $M \subseteq \overline{M}$ one has $M \cup \dot{M} \subseteq \overline{M}$. For the reverse inclusion, consider an arbitrary element $x \in \overline{M} \setminus M$ and an arbitrary neighbourhood $V \in \mathscr{V}_{\mathscr{T}}(x)$. By definition one must have $M \cap V \neq \varnothing$ and keeping in mind that $x \notin M$ we derive $M=M \setminus \{x\}$ and therefore $V \cap M=V \cap M \setminus \{x\} \neq \varnothing$. This shows that $x \in \dot{M}$ is an accumulation point of $M$ and establishes the inclusion $\overline{M} \setminus M \subseteq \dot{M}$, which is equivalent to $\overline{M} \subseteq M \cup \dot{M}$.

The description $\overline{M}=M \cup \dot{M}$ is thus fully proved for any subset $M \subseteq X$.

Comment: This was really helpful! Thanks

Comment: Maybe just one thing: "accumulation point of M it will automatically be adherent to M" Shouldn't it be $\overline{M}$ for the second M?

Comment: @Averroes2 Glad you found it useful. An adherent point of $M$ means an element of $\overline{M}$. Since the closure operator is idempotent ($\overline{\overline{M}}=\overline{M}$), it is true that a point is adherent to $\overline{M}$ if and only if it is adherent to $M$, however the formulation is correct as it is given above (especially since it focuses on the comparison between points which are of accumulation respectively adherent to one and the same subset $M$).